# How to get No. of Months from different dates which are coming from same column?

Tags: sql

Please  help me to resolve the following issue.

Scenario:
I have to calculate each Meter usage. In the table, I have Meter Installation date and Meter Removal date. One Meter could have been installed and removed multiple times in different locations. Both Installation and Removal dates are stored in the same column (LOC_DTTM).

Question:
How do I get the total numbers of Months for each Meter usage if both dates are stored in the same column?

I did Rank first based on date ascending, then would like to do `(First removal date - First installation date) + (second Removal date - re-installed date) + ( n - n)`.

Please correct me if my approach is wrong, your help would be appreciated.

Query:

```
select a.meter_id, a.loc_dttm,row_number() Over (order by a.loc_dttm asc) as rank
from cisadm.CI_MTR_LOC_HIS a
where 
meter_id in ('0069890525') ;
```

Comment: quick clarify to see if I got your question...but each install / removal date will be a different line, so you have many rows in CI_MTR_LOC_HIS for each meter_id?    Sound right?

Comment: Is there something in CI_MTR_LOC_HIS that indicates it is an install or a removal?  Or is it just 1st row is an install, 2nd a removal, 3rd an install, 4th a removal, etc, just alternating?

Comment: Some sample data wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
meter_id
,sum(Months) as TotalMonths
FROM (
   SELECT
   b.meter_id
   ,(datediff(mm,b.loc_dttm,c.loc_dttm)) as Months
   FROM 
      (select a.meter_id, a.loc_dttm,row_number() Over (order by a.loc_dttm asc) as rank
      from cisadm.CI_MTR_LOC_HIS a
      ) b
   JOIN (select a.meter_id, a.loc_dttm,row_number() Over (order by a.loc_dttm asc) as rank
   from cisadm.CI_MTR_LOC_HIS a
   ) c on b.rank=c.rank-1 and b.rank % 2 <>0
) d
where meter_id in ('0069890525')
group by meter_id
```

Try this.

Comment: If you use the WITH clause you won't need to do the same select twice. You could also use LAG and get rid of the join entirely

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your need is to perform a calculation the date data within "a.loc_dttm" column, which contains two dates.

I would suggest: create temp table with two columns, (date1,date2) where the dateN will be inserted into the temp table from your main table as:

```
date1= Trim(Left(a.loc_dttm, InStr(a.loc_dttm, " ") - 1)),
date2= Trim(Mid(a.loc_dttm, InStr(a.loc_dttm, " ") + 1))
```

where " " is the character used to split the dates.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood how the dates are stored; the column does not contain two values, but one column store two different type of dates, one row for install and one row for removal.